# densely defined map

Tags: functional-analysis

$H$ is a Hilbert space with norm $|\cdot|$, and their is another norm $\|\cdot\|$ which satisfy $\|\cdot\|\le c|\cdot|$, take $W:=\overline{H}^{\|\cdot\|}$.

let $i:H\to W$ be the inclusion map, then why the dual map $i^*:W^*\to H^*=H$ is densely defined and continuous?

---

from $\|\cdot\|\le c|\cdot|$, I can prove that $i$ is continuous. But I don't understand why $i^*$ is densely defined. From the adjoint operator theory, $i^*$ can be defined on $W^*$ *everywhere* and satisfy
$$\langle i(x),y^*\rangle=\langle x,i^*(y)\rangle$$
for all $x\in H$ and $y^*\in W^*$, and $i^*$ is continuous, so why "densely defined"?

Is $i^*$ a inclusion map?

Comment: A dense subspace means that the intervals of the metric in the norm-space are all relatively open. That is each ball of convergence overlap, creating an isometric topology.